# how to copy the value of a 'contenteditable' element and insert it to other html template? Django

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to copy the value of a 'textarea' input (where the user provides a text) and use it as it is in a "draft page" before posting it.

I won't paste here all my code but the relevant things.

First of all I'm using Django Framework, and I added to the base.html template the Jquery script.

In other html template called 'userblog' I added a mini text editor where 1 of his elements is a paragraph and you can change its content.

**The end part of it:**

```
  <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" name="post_content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
  <p id="editMode"><input type="checkbox" name="switchMode" id="switchBox" onchange="setDocMode(this.checked);" /> <label for="switchBox">Show HTML</label></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
  {% csrf_token %}

  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var textAreaContent = $('textBox').val();
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
{% endblock %}
```

And in the draft.html I wrote:

```
{% extends "TheApp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="container">
 <h1>This is a preview of you're post:
  <script type="text/javascript" src="userblog.html">
   document.write(textAreaContent)
   </script>
 </h1>




{% endblock %}
```

The view is:

```
def draft(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        draft = request.POST.get('post_content')
        return render(request, 'TheApp/draft.html', {'draft':draft})

    else:
        return render(request, 'TheApp/userblog.html',)
```

The problem is that it does not display my paragraph content.. whats wrong in my code?

I'm new to this, I learn a bit python and the Django framework.. towards the process i touched a bit of HTML & CSS but I know almost nothing about JS..

Comment: I suspect you are not sending textAreaContent to your template. The <script> tag looks strange. Why the 'src' attribute? Are you expecting to 'pull' the content from your 'user.html'? That will not work. Could you provide your view to access 'draft.html'?

Comment: BTW: Your container is missing the closing </div>

Comment: Sorry, I had few mistakes explaining it. I fixed it and added the view

Comment: I used the src because Im using a variable i defined in the source html template.. I thought its the right way..

Answer (score 0):

Your "userblog.html" is indeed not getting the variable you expected.

In your view in the line

```
return render(request, 'TheApp/draft.html', {'draft':draft})
```

you are sending a context variable called "draft" to your template, which can be accessed in the template like so

```
<h1>This is a preview of you're post:
  {{ draft }}
</h1>
```

As you can see you do not need any javascript for your scenario at all.

Technically you can mix the context variables and javascript (I think):

```
<h1>This is a preview of you're post:
  <script>
   document.write({{ draft }})
   </script>
</h1>
```

This does not make sense here, but just in case your code is just an example to understand some basics.

EDIT:

Of course you must make sure that the post_content is actually sent to your view. That means in your first template you need a textarea or input for your editable content. The only thing I see is a `<div>` with that name. A `<div>` does not send anything. So your form in your "userblog.html" this could be something like this:

```
<form action='/draft/' method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="post_content">

    </textarea>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then with my code above your draft.html will display what you entered.

Comment: Thank you but thats what I did at the beggining and it dosent display the draft contest value... thats why I tried js

Comment: @Amit Lus Well, the solution should work. Then your draft variable is probably an empty ''. Could you post the template "userblog.html"? JS is not your solution.

Comment: @Amit Lus Sorry, just saw that the end of your "userblog.html" is already there. Added some additional information above.

Comment: Ok the problem with the way you said is that it returns a NULL.. thats why I changed my way and thought to use js.

Comment: Maybe i should save it or something.. ill try it when ill be on the pc..

Comment: I am almost certain the problem is your user blog.html. You don't need to save the content before passing it to the draft.html and you do not need any JS for that.

Comment: Could not solve the problem yet.... would you like to add me on discord or something and try to help me?

Comment: @Amit Lus Please update your current code so we can see what you have tried so far

Comment: I changed almost every thing in the project, but now I'm stuck because I made a list view and iterate through it in my template and it dosent display anything at all....
What are the chances that you would like to help me in private? maybe via screen share on any app like discord? it will be a lot easier.. :)))

Comment: Hey bro I did it.. after long hours of tests.. I'm not share what exactly did it, but I realized that both ListView & UpdateView are using by default the context as post_list and I had 2 different pages- each one refers by the other View so I thought maybe there is a duplicate that interapts.. so I set the ListView context name, and I also changed the tag in the template to {%block body_block%} instead {%block content%} . I guess 1 of them or both were the solution. Thank you for you're help anyway dude :)